# How to parse a multidimensional JSON?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I've got a JSON object containing some voter registration information that I'm trying to parse. I would like to retrieve the PersonKey from this object and store it in a variable.

```
[{"VoterKey":"31165750","PersonKey":"31165750","RNCID":"9959639415","State":"DC","Juriscode":"1100000000","Jurisname":"District of Columbia","CountyFIPS":"0","MCD":"","CNTY":"","Town":"","Ward":"07","Precinct":"097","Ballotbox":"","PrecinctName":"097","CD":"0","SD":"0","LD":"0","LDS":"","NamePrefix":"","FirstName":"MARCUS","MiddleName":"L","LastName":"JONES","NameSuffix":"","Sex":"M","BirthYear":"1982","BirthMonth":"11","BirthDay":"27","OfficialParty":"D","RNCCalcParty":"5","StateVoterID":"000129543","JurisdictionVoterID":"","RegistrationDate":"20030521","VoterStatus":"A","PermAbs":"","SelfReportedDemographic":"","ModeledEthnicity":"E1","ModeledReligion":"P","ModeledEthnicGroup":"Z","HHSEQ":"194061","HTSEQ":"2","RegistrationAddressKey":"19811832","RegistrationAddr1":"231 51ST ST NE","RegistrationAddr2":"","RegCity":"WASHINGTON","RegSta":"DC","RegZip5":"20019","RegZip4":"5420","RADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","RADR_LastGeoCode":"2013-02-04","MailingAddressKey":"19811832","MailingAddr1":"231 51ST ST NE","MailingAddr2":"","MailCity":"WASHINGTON","MailSta":"DC","MailZip5":"20019","MailZip4":"5420","MADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","AreaCode":"---","TelephoneNUm":"-------"},{"VoterKey":"31145016","PersonKey":"31145016","RNCID":"9959778025","State":"DC","Juriscode":"1100000000","Jurisname":"District of Columbia","CountyFIPS":"0","MCD":"","CNTY":"","Town":"","Ward":"07","Precinct":"102","Ballotbox":"","PrecinctName":"102","CD":"0","SD":"0","LD":"0","LDS":"","NamePrefix":"","FirstName":"MARCUS","MiddleName":"J","LastName":"JONES","NameSuffix":"","Sex":"M","BirthYear":"1900","BirthMonth":"01","BirthDay":"01","OfficialParty":"N","RNCCalcParty":"3","StateVoterID":"100019252","JurisdictionVoterID":"","RegistrationDate":"20100716","VoterStatus":"A","PermAbs":"","SelfReportedDemographic":"","ModeledEthnicity":"E1","ModeledReligion":"P","ModeledEthnicGroup":"Z","HHSEQ":"194001","HTSEQ":"1","RegistrationAddressKey":"19888718","RegistrationAddr1":"109 36TH ST NE","RegistrationAddr2":"2","RegCity":"WASHINGTON","RegSta":"DC","RegZip5":"20019","RegZip4":"2602","RADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","RADR_LastGeoCode":"2013-02-04","MailingAddressKey":"19888718","MailingAddr1":"109 36TH ST NE","MailingAddr2":"2","MailCity":"WASHINGTON","MailSta":"DC","MailZip5":"20019","MailZip4":"2602","MADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","AreaCode":"---","TelephoneNUm":"-------"},{"VoterKey":"31371499","PersonKey":"31371499","RNCID":"9959695444","State":"DC","Juriscode":"1100000000","Jurisname":"District of Columbia","CountyFIPS":"0","MCD":"","CNTY":"","Town":"","Ward":"07","Precinct":"097","Ballotbox":"","PrecinctName":"097","CD":"0","SD":"0","LD":"0","LDS":"","NamePrefix":"","FirstName":"MARCUS","MiddleName":"D","LastName":"JONES","NameSuffix":"","Sex":"M","BirthYear":"1900","BirthMonth":"01","BirthDay":"01","OfficialParty":"D","RNCCalcParty":"5","StateVoterID":"070016862","JurisdictionVoterID":"","RegistrationDate":"20070822","VoterStatus":"A","PermAbs":"","SelfReportedDemographic":"","ModeledEthnicity":"E1","ModeledReligion":"P","ModeledEthnicGroup":"Z","HHSEQ":"194398","HTSEQ":"1","RegistrationAddressKey":"126729320","RegistrationAddr1":"5019 FITCH PL NE","RegistrationAddr2":"","RegCity":"WASHINGTON","RegSta":"DC","RegZip5":"20019","RegZip4":"5447","RADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","RADR_LastGeoCode":"2013-02-04","MailingAddressKey":"126729320","MailingAddr1":"5019 FITCH PL NE","MailingAddr2":"","MailCity":"WASHINGTON","MailSta":"DC","MailZip5":"20019","MailZip4":"5447","MADR_LastCleanse":"2013-02-04","AreaCode":"---","TelephoneNUm":"-------"}]
```

Any suggestions how best to handle this?

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), read the docs for info on how to.

Comment: json_decode using the true flag will convert it into a php array, in case you prefer working that.

Comment: @entiendoNull @Jite Already tried it. When I `json_decode` and `var_dump` the `$result`, it is `NULL`.

Comment: Didn't there used to be more comments here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_decode` -- here's the [entry in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Example:

```
$data = '[{"VoterKey":"31165750","PersonKey":"31165750","RNCID":"9959639415"}]';
$arr = json_decode($data);
$person_key = $arr[0]->PersonKey;
```